# Unable to access/expand Firebase Realtime data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to access/expand the Firebase Realtime database as shown in the picture, but somehow I am not able to. The page becomes unresponsive after few minutes. Is there any other way to access it? What could be the possible problem here?
Thanks
[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF5Pu.png)

Comment: Try a different browser (Firefox, Safari) and report back.

Comment: Hi Jay, it worked with Firefox. Although it crashes the Firefox browser as well, somehow I am able to expand the node unlike in Google Chrome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying to expand the nodes individually by clicking of the small plus at each node?

Comment: That was the problem actually. The solution by Jay above did the job.